# Software for Webcam 180º Rotation

Tags: display, webcam

I have a very un-orthodox desk setup, I have a 32" LG UltraFina 5k Monitor above another ultra-wide monitor. (never is too much)

LG UltraFine has a built-in WebCam, but 'cos the Monitor is so High the webcam points to my head, LOL.

So I was looking to rotate the Monitor and set the config of the Display to 180º, so the webcam points to my face, but so far I haven't found any software or settings to rotate the webcam...

is that a possibility or am I stock in my odd desk configuration and have to look up for a better setup (please don't agree with me and hope is any other possibility for webcam settings).

Comment: I'm trying to find the same answer. I have a 5K Ultrafine, rotated on a vesa mount. MacOs allows me to rotate the screen 90, but the webcam does not rotate when using google meet. Is the only answer to get another webcam?